# Why does JNI/JNA segfault with simple calls fprintf(stdout "hello world\n")?

Tags: java-native-interface, jna, glibc

Is there any reason that a native JNI function should cause a segfault when calling

```
fprintf(stdout, "hello world\n")
```

?

The following succeeds in calling several native functions, but fails at testPrintStdOut (which just calls printf) and segfaults. Is it possible that libc's static initializers aren't called, or that there's a mismatch with libc versions? (and if so, how to diagnose?)

- scala 2.10
- java 1.7 0_45
- jna 4.1.0
- gcc 4.8.2
- Ubuntu 14.0.4

---

JNATest.h

```
import com.sun.jna.Library
import com.sun.jna.Native
import com.sun.jna.Platform

trait NativeLibrary extends Library {
  def testVoidVoid(): Unit
  def testPingInt(i: Integer): Integer
  def testStringLen(str: String): Integer
  def testPrintStdOut(): Unit
  def testPrintStdErr(): Unit
  def testPrintCOut(): Unit
  def testPrintCErr(): Unit
}

object NativeLibrary {
  val LIBRARY: NativeLibrary = Native.loadLibrary("NativeLibrary", classOf[NativeServiceLibrary]).asInstanceOf[NativeServiceLibrary]
}
```

JNATest.scala

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.junit.Assert._
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Ignore
import org.junit.Test

class JNATest {
  val logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName())

  @Test
  def testJNABasics(): Unit = {
    val lib = NativeLibrary.LIBRARY
    logger.info("voidvoid")
    lib.testVoidVoid()

    logger.info("stringlen")
    assertTrue( lib.testStringLen("hello")==5 )

    logger.info("pingint")
    assertTrue( lib.testPingInt( 54321 )==54321 )

    logger.info("stdout")
    lib.testPrintStdOut()

    logger.info("cout")
    lib.testPrintCOut()

    logger.info("stderr")
    lib.testPrintStdErr()

    logger.info("cerr")
    lib.testPrintCErr()

    logger.info("All OK")
  }
}
```

NativeLibrary.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

  void testVoidVoid(void);  
  int testPingInt(int i);  
  int  testStringLen(char const* str);  
  void testPrintStdOut(void);  
  void testPrintStdErr(void);  
  void testPrintCOut(void);  
  void testPrintCErr(void);  

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

NativeLibrary.cpp -- compiled into libNativeLibrary.so

```
#include “NativeLibrary.h”
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

void testVoidVoid(void) {}
int testPingInt(int i ) { return i; }  
int  testStringLen(char const* str) { return strlen(str); }
void testPrintStdOut(void) { fprintf(stdout, "stdout: hello world\n"); fflush(stdout); }
void testPrintStdErr(void) { fprintf(stderr, "stderr: hello world\n"); fflush(stderr); }
void testPrintCOut(void) { std::cout << "cout: hello world" << std::endl; }
void testPrintCErr(void) { std::cout << "cout: hello world" << std::endl; }
```

There are additional functions in my source, but overall libNativeLibrary.so depends on:

```
$ ldd libNativeServices.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff70ffe000)
    libmysqlclient.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18 (0x00007f11020fc000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1101ede000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1101cd5000)
    libthrift-0.9.2.so => /usr/local/lib/libthrift-0.9.2.so (0x00007f1101a31000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f110172d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1101426000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1101210000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1100e4a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1102f4c000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f1100c30000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1100a2c000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f11007ce000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f11003f3000)
```

The segfault...

```
...
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002b0d965f4893, pid=31096, tid=47336869742336
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libNativeLibrary.so+0x2893]  testPrintStdOut+0x8
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/xxx/src/core or core.31096
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/xxx/src/hs_err_pid31096.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain it won't be needed (you're supplying the newline), so have you tried removing the `fflush(stdout)` and trying again?

Comment: Test it with vanilla Java to eliminate any Scala plumbing from the equation.